# how do I translate a vector from xyz to xy using a plane normal? (using hlsl)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, hlsl

```
float3 plane_normal = mul(mesh_Object2World, v.normal);
o.normal = o.worldPos - _Mouse.xyz;
```

//next, I dont know how to translate "o.normal" to 2d using "plane_normal"

Comment: You mean project it onto the plane?

Comment: Yes, so that it is in XY dimensions

Comment: Does this answer your question [Unity shader (hlsl) equivalent of Vector3.ProjectOnPlane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471226/7111561) ?

Comment: no, imagine that plane normal is a screen and you need to project a 3d vector onto it. The resulting vector will be in XY right?

Comment: yes, so? I don't understand where you are going with your question ... by screen you mean the actual device screen (pixel space)? And what do you mean by XY ? Local space/ pixel space / global space? Maybe it would help to add a bit more detailed description of your actual use case / goal

Comment: i trying to implement mesh texture painting using normal projection. The source vector is the distance from the drawing point to the pixel. I need to translate this vector to 2d space using plane normal to determine the coordinates for tex2d

Comment: and what exactly is wrong in the link? I think it shows three methods for projecting any 3D vector onto any plane using the given normal doesn't it?

Comment: I've already solved the problem, thanks anyway

Comment: @OynamaliKanal Hey, can you please explain how you managed to solve this issue, i am facing a simular issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But in Unity a 2D project and a 3D project is the same. All that is different is the default background, the Camera Perspective and 3D makes use of the z plane which is depth.

Meaning `Vector3(x, y, 0) == Vector2 (x, y)` all you need to do is set the `Vector3.z = 0`. So the normal for `Vector3(x, y, 0)` and `Vector2 (x, y)` are the same.

Comment: I am aware of this, but it only works if the direction of the vector is the same as plane normal

Comment: OP's question is about HLSL (shader) and even in Unity c# that is only true for the one case where you are actually speaking about the world XZ plane with y = 0